# How to make a Progress/Message Window where each line can be different font, size, color?

Tags: wpf, text, mvvm, colors

I tried to make a TextBlock in my View that will display whatever message I send to it. It just keeps appending a new line each time it writes. I want the ability to write in different font, size, and color per line.

I have found examples that do it for ListViews, and RichTextBox. I don't care what control it is. It just needs to follow the MVVM format and that is where I am having troubles with those examples.

For those that are familiar with the Command Window, how you can make a batch file and 'echo' lines to the display?  That is what I am trying to do.

Comment: @afuzzyllama - You can edit, but you can't help?

Comment: ListViews and RichTextBox would be the ideal controls.  Perhaps provide more detail as to what you've tried and/or how the examples are confusing you with respect to MVVM pattern.

Comment: @MarkLallemont - I was reviewing your question for the community.  It does not mean I know the answer.

Comment: Can you share what examples you have looked at that you are having trouble with?  How are you calling this view? Asynchronously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found [Alternate row color in Listbox](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/alternate-row-color-in-listbox-in-wpf/) and used [Bind foreground of Textblock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601489/how-can-i-bind-foreground-to-a-property-in-my-viewmodel). Realized I needed to make a class to hold my string and color. Put that class in an ObservableCollection, and bind to the ObservableCollection.

My new class:

```
public class DisplayData
{
    public string _string { get; set; }
    public System.Windows.Media.Brush _color { get; set; }
    public int _fontSize { get; set; }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="Progress_Window" ItemsSource="{Binding pb._displayString}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding _string}" Foreground="{Binding _color}" FontSize="{Binding _fontSize}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Where pb is my local class variable in my VM.

Code in Model:

```
public ObservableCollection<DisplayData> _displayString { get; set; }
...
_displayString = new ObservableCollection<DisplayData>();
string _error = "Error Opening COM Port";
_displayString.Add(new DisplayData { _string = _error, _color = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red, _fontSize = 20 });
```